# Neo4j Unmanaged Extension unit testing for version 2.2.3

Tags: neo4j, unmanaged

I like to create unit tests for my unmanaged extension I wrote for a small Neo4j project.

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder()
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "512M")
                .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.string_block_size, "60" )
                .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.array_block_size, "300" )
                .newGraphDatabase();
```

I want to use an approach similar to the code above in my @Before test class - which I understand is the new way to write unit tests.

I like to ask:

1. How I can turn the automatic authentication off using config settings
2. How I can register our extension

I manage to achieve my goal with the code below but I get bunch of deprecated warnings.

```
ImpermanentGraphDatabase db = new ImpermanentGraphDatabase();
ServerConfigurator config = new ServerConfigurator(db);
        config.configuration().setProperty("dbms.security.auth_enabled", false);
        config.getThirdpartyJaxRsPackages().add(new ThirdPartyJaxRsPackage("com.mine.graph.neo4j", "/extensions/mine"));
testBootstrapper = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(db, config);
testBootstrapper.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solutions is to create your own TestServer based on the Neo4j test classes so that you can set properties and load the UMX

```
public class Neo4jTestServer  {
private AbstractNeoServer server;
private GraphDatabaseService database;

public Neo4jTestServer() {

    try {
        ServerControls controls = TestServerBuilders.newInProcessBuilder()
                .withExtension("/fd", "org.flockdata.neo4j")
                .withConfig("dbms.security.auth_enabled", "false")
                .newServer();

        initialise(controls);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error starting in-process server",e);
    }

}

private void initialise(ServerControls controls) throws Exception {

    Field field = InProcessServerControls.class.getDeclaredField("server");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    server = (AbstractNeoServer) field.get(controls);
    database = server.getDatabase().getGraph();
}

/**
 * Retrieves the base URL of the Neo4j database server used in the test.
 *
 * @return The URL of the Neo4j test server
 */
public String url() {
    return server.baseUri().toString();
}}
```

You will also need an InProcessServer to return your TestServer with a UMX

```
public class Neo4jInProcessServer implements Neo4jServer{
private Neo4jTestServer testServer;

public Neo4jInProcessServer()  {
    this.testServer = new Neo4jTestServer();
}

public String url() {
    return testServer.url();
}}
```

Finally, you need to return the InProcessServer from your configuration class

```
    @Override
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {

    return new Neo4jInProcessServer();
}
```